# Show / hide tables using slider

Tags: javascript, html-table, slider, show-hide

I'm trying to use a slider to show/hide tables and change a number on the screen at the same time with the below:

```
<input id="scaleSlider" type="range" value="1" min="1"  max="9" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value), showOrHide(this.value)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue) {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showOrHide(newValue) {
        if (("newValue").value = 1) {
            document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
        }
        if (("newValue").value = 2) {
            document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="block";
            document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
        }
}

</script>
```

"range" gets set fine and displays the number but I cant get the tables to toggle"

---

What I have now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(newValue)
{
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
</script>
</td>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showOrHide(newValue){

    if(newValue == 1) {
document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
}
    if(newValue == 2) {
document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="block";
document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
}
}   

</script>
```

Still not hiding or showing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onchange needs a semicolon: `onchange="showValue(this.value); showOrHide(this.value);"` rather than a comma. You will also need the brace that Cerbrus mentioned. Also `("newValue").value` simply needs to be `newValue` and make your comparisons with that. You are passing in the actual value of the slider as `newValue`, so you don't need to do anything special to reference it. Again, Cerbrus is also correct about `=` needing to be `==` to test for equality rather than doing an assignment.

So you end up with `if (newValue == 1) { ... }` as the form of your if statements.

Also, `document.getElementById(guest2)` and the rest need to be in the form `document.getElementById("guest2")` because guest2 is not a variable in your javascript but the id of your table. Which means you need to pass it in as a string not a reference.

Also `document.getElementById("range")` needs to be `document.getElementById("scaleSlider")` which is the id rather than the type.

Comment: The semicolon thing is not mandatory. Javascript only requires it to distinguish multiple statements, if they're on the same line.

Comment: Oh derp, ignore what I just said -.- My bad.

Comment: Cerbrus && mafafu  you guys nailed it! Man I didnt realize how far off I was. Thank you both very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you format your code properly, you will see you're missing a `}` to close `function showOrHide(newValue)`.

Also, `("newValue").value` will not work. Just use `newValue`:

```
if(newValue == 1)
```

**Edit**
Also, it seems you're using `.value = 2` in your `if`'s, this should be `.value == 2` (Same for `==1`)

Comment: Sorry did that deleting some other stuff that didnt work. However it doesnt work after correcting that mistake.

Comment: I tried  if ($("newValue").value = 1) but still got nothing, I feel like im doing this all wrong. is there a simpler way to call a function for each value of the slider?

Comment: what do you mean "jQuery addded" ? i changed the if statement to  if($("newValue").value == 1)

Comment: Nevermind the thing about jQuery, misinterpretation from my part. use this: `if(newValue == 1)`. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Also, keep in mind you still have a lot of `style.display="none";` in the last bit of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="scaleSlider" type="range" value="1" min="1"  max="9" step="1" onchange="showOrHide(this.value)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showOrHide(newValue) {
        var newValue = document.getElementById("range").value;
        if (newValue == 1) {
            document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
        }
        if (newValue == 2) {
            document.getElementById(guest2).style.display="block";
            document.getElementById(guest3).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest4).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest5).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest6).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest7).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest8).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById(guest9).style.display="none";
        }
}
</script>
```